# Java - Concurrent Modification Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, concurrency

I am getting a concurrent modification exception on the following code:

```
        for(Iterator<Tile> iter = spawner.activeTiles.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Tile tile = iter.next();
            canvas.drawRect(tile, tile.getColor());
        }
```

I understand that concurrent modification happens when it is changed while it is iterating(adding/removing inside of the iteration). I also understand that they can happen when multithreading which is where I think my problem is.

In my game I have a few timers that run on threads. I have a spawner, which adds values to activeTiles on each tick. I then have a 2 timers, one for fading in and one for fading out. Without giving away my game, the tile is basically removed from the list when the fade out has finished, or when the player taps the tile. So there are a few instances where the tiles are removed from the list of tiles:

```
for(Iterator<Tile> iter = spawner.activeTiles.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Tile tile = iter.next();

                if(tile.contains(x, y) && tile.equals(spawner.activeTiles.get(0))) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(50);

                    tile.setBroken(true);
                    score ++;
                    spawner.setTileDelayInfo();
                    iter.remove();
```

and before each new spawn, it removes all of the failed tiles:

```
private void removeFailedTiles() {
    for(Iterator<Tile> iter = activeTiles.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Tile tile = iter.next();

        if(tile.isFailed()) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

It almost seems to happen randomly. So I think it has to do something with timing, but I am new to this kind of exception and don't really know what to look for or why this is happening.

Comment: If it "seems to happen randomly" it's likely a multithreading issue.

Comment: @Ata, he's using an iterator, is not the same question. Actually, using the iterator is the answer to that question, so he's doing it the right way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreading can be a source of `ConcurrentModificationException`s.  It can happen when one thread is modifying the structure of the collection while another thread has an `Iterator` iterating over it.  This can lead to unexpected states in your application when the state of the collection changes when a section of code needs a consistent view of the data.  This is needed when you're iterating over a collection of `Tile`s.

You need to syncrhonize access to the `activeTiles` collection.  Anything that modifies this collection structurally (add or remove), or iterates over it, must synchronize on this collection.

Add a `synchronized (activeTiles)` block around all code that iterates or structuraly modifies `activeTiles`.  This includes all 3 code snippets you've provided here.

Alternatively, you can make the 3 methods corresponding to your code snippets `synchronized`.

Either way, no other `Thread` can execute any of the `synchronized` blocks until another `Thread` is finished with its `syncrhonized` section, preventing the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: adding synchronized on function would synchronize access to function but not to the data-structures that are being used inside it. It can still happen that two different functions are accessing same list.

Comment: @Ata Adding `synchronized` on these methods will lock on the object instance, which is the same object instance in each thread.  The effect is the same as in `synchronized(activeTiles)`; the code that iterates or modifies `activeTiles` can only be executed by one thread at a time.

Comment: Yes, all code that either iterates over the `activeTiles` or structurally modifies it must be `synchronized`.

Comment: What is the syntax for this? Ive never used synchronized before

Comment: just `synchronized(activeTiles) { .... }`, or use a Lock as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: @KyleJensen There is the [syntax synchronized methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) and the [syntax for synchronized blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Comment: @rgettman "Alternatively, you can make the 3 methods corresponding to your code snippets `synchronized`" -- that's not true since `synchronized` locks the object, whose method is iterating `activeTiles`; this can happen in more than one object.

Comment: @steffen If there were more than one object, then each would have its own copy of `activeTiles` and there would be no `ConcurrentModificationException` to begin with.  There's only one object with `activeTiles` here, and as long as the object being locked is consistently the same, then the code will become thread-safe, and the `ConcurrentModificationException` will be avoided.

Comment: @rgettman Why would they have their own copies? They all share the same member `activeTiles`. Problem is: `synchronized` locks the object that's calling `iterator()` on `activeTiles`.

Comment: @steffen The assumption is that `activeTiles` is an instance variable in some class that also has methods containing the code in the question.  Also, there's nothing wrong with using either `activeTiles` or the current object as a lock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78136/discussion-between-steffen-and-rgettman).

Answer (score 2):

The good news: you nailed the root cause of the problem in your question - you can't have multiple threads accessing a list at the same time unless they're all just reading.

You can address this in one of two ways, depending on how the rest of your code operates.  The most 'correct' way is steffen's answer: any list access should be guarded with a `synchronized` block, and that includes holding the lock for the full duration of any list iterations.  Note that if you do this, you want to do as little work as possible while holding the lock - in particular, it's a bad idea to do any sort of listener callbacks while holding a lock.

Your second option is to use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), which is thread-safe and doesn't require any external synchronization - but any modifications to the list (add/remove/replace calls) become significantly more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe to remove elements with an `Iterator` that supports element-removal, when you're iterating the collection in another thread.

Acquire a [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) in all threads on `activeTiles` before iterating them.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make your list thread-safe. Use [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29).

```
threadSafeActiveTiles = Collections.synchronizedList(activeTiles);
```

Mind that you must synchronize on that list when iterating over it:

```
synchronized (threadSafeActiveTiles) {
    for (Iterator<Tile> it = threadSafeActiveTiles.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Tile tile = it.next();
        // ...
    }
}
```

You then can safely have multiple threads modifying the list, which seems to be your case.

The list returned by `Collections.synchronizedList()` saves you from having to use the synchronized block (above) in single operations on that list, like `add(e)`, `size()`, `get(i)` and so on...

Comment: synchronizedList isn't sufficient if you're iterating over the list, since there's no lock being held over the full length of the iteration - so you can still get ConcurrentModificationExceptions just like it wasn't.